# How set background color for buttons using xml files?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, colors

i create this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/light_blue"
            android:centerColor="@color/dark_blue"
            android:endColor="@color/light_purple"
           >
        </gradient>
            <corners
                android:radius="30dp">

            </corners>

        </shape>

    </item>

</selector>
```

and i trying to set this file to my button background.but problem is background dose not accept colors of xml file.it is use backgroundTint colors and not the colors i set above.

THIS IS MY ACTIVITY_XML

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/temp_l"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:background="@drawable/temp_shape"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.143" />
```

i searched in youtube and saw that eveyone did what i did but they get result and im not.

sorry about my english.its not very well.

Comment: Are you using `MaterialButton` or `AppCompatButton` from `androidx` package?

Comment: No,its regular button.i did not use any package to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using `android:backgroundTint="@null"` with `android` namespace, but you need to set `app:backgroundTint="@null"` with `app` namespace instead

**Side note:**

You should wrap the xml drawable into a `layer-list` as long as you have no need to the `selector`, so you might change it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#055D93"
                android:endColor="@color/light_purple"
                android:startColor="@color/light_blue" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp">

            </corners>

        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Preview

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.this line: app:backgroundTint="@null"    solved my problem.